# The type initializer for 'Nuget.EnvironmentUtility' threw an exception

Tags: exception, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I'm on my second computer with this same issue. I assume it's got to be a combination of tools I use in Visual Studio, but I often get this error.

```
Install-Package : The type initializer for 'NuGet.EnvironmentUtility' threw an exception.
At line:1 char:35
+ get-project -all | Install-Package <<<<  xamarin.forms
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], TypeInitializationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.TypeInitializationException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I end up messing around with uninstalling/reinstalling nuget, rebooting my machine, and deleting config files until it works again. I never know exactly which part actually fixed it.

Has anyone else seen this? What are the right steps to resolve?

---

> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013 Version 12.0.31101.00 Update
>   4 Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.5.50938
>
> Installed Version: Professional
>
> Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013   06177-004-0444002-02083
>   Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013
>
> Visual Basic 2013   06177-004-0444002-02083 Microsoft Visual Basic
>   2013
>
> Visual C# 2013   06177-004-0444002-02083 Microsoft Visual C# 2013
>
> Visual C++ 2013   06177-004-0444002-02083 Microsoft Visual C++ 2013
>
> Visual F# 2013   06177-004-0444002-02083 Microsoft Visual F# 2013
>
> Visual Studio 2013 Code Analysis Spell Checker
>   06177-004-0444002-02083 Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2013 Code Analysis
>   Spell Checker
>
> Portions of International CorrectSpell™ spelling correction system ©
>   1993 by Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.
>
> The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Third
>   Edition Copyright © 1992 Houghton Mifflin Company. Electronic version
>   licensed from Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights
>   reserved.
>
> Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   1.0 Application
>   Insights Tools for Visual Studio
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools   12.4.51016.0 Microsoft Web Developer Tools
>   contains the following components: Support for creating and opening
>   ASP.NET web projects Browser Link: A communication channel between
>   Visual Studio and browsers Editor extensions for HTML, CSS, and
>   JavaScript Page Inspector: Inspection tool for ASP.NET web projects
>   Scaffolding: A framework for building and running code generators
>   Server Explorer extensions for Microsoft Azure Websites Web
>   publishing: Extensions for publishing ASP.NET web projects to hosting
>   providers, on-premises servers, or Microsoft Azure
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.21001.0 For additional
>   information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.21010.0 For additional
>   information, visit http://www.asp.net/
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.3 Provides common services for use by Azure
>   Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> JetBrains ReSharper Platform 6   Build 6.0.20141219.120158 on
>   2014-12-19 12:56:02Z JetBrains ReSharper Platform package for
>   Microsoft Visual Studio. For more information about ReSharper
>   Platform, visit http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper. Copyright © 2015
>   JetBrains, Inc.
>
> Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.3 Microsoft Azure Mobile
>   Services Tools
>
> NuGet Package Manager   2.8.60318.734 NuGet Package Manager in Visual
>   Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit
>   http://docs.nuget.org/.
>
> PowerShell Tools   1.3 Provides file classification services using
>   PowerShell
>
> PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2 Microsoft Visual Studio
>   extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive
>   Analytics product.
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   12.0.41012.0 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> Windows Phone 8.1 SDK Integration   1.0 This package integrates the
>   tools for the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK into the menus and controls of
>   Visual Studio.
>
> Xamarin   3.11.445.0 (5061f92) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin.Android   5.1.0.115 (d23da369e436488f38c8ab8fe8a9ae7d9ea5256b)
>   Visual Studio plugin to enable development for Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin.Forms Intellisense   1.0 Provides intellisense for
>   Xamarin.Forms in the XML editor.
>
> Xamarin.iOS   8.10.0.0 (7741cc495ab0baf04ff0405d0604bc27f0ecae2e)
>   Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS.
>
> Xamarin.iOS Unified Migration   1.0 Automated migration for Xamarin
>   iOS Classic projects to Unified
>
> Xamarin.TestCloud.Integration   1.0 Early preview of Xamarin Test
>   Cloud integration

Answer (score 8):

I was getting this and solved it by closing ALL instances of VS before reopening the solution with the problem.

Comment: Here, here, VS2013 and Xamarin (no ReSharper), restarting VS resolved issue

Answer (score 3):

Have gotten the exact same issue multiple times and have not been able to figure it out. Seeing your list of installs make me think it must be a mix of Visual Studio, ReSharper, and Xamarin, which I also have installed.

I just really do not want to give up my ReSharper!

edit: I have seen a bug or two created for very similar issues involving Xamarin's Visual Studio plugin generating weird errors. The one I saw is supposed to be fixed or will be in alpha soon. Although I cannot say for sure if it will address this specific issue. If I find the link to the bug again I will post it here.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, also using ReSharper and Xamarin. In my case it was caused by a conflict of the extensions.
I removed all the excess extensions (in my case - everything about "Azure", "Advertising" and "pubCenter") and now it seems to work.
As long as removing of Microsoft Advertising SDK is non a trivial thing, suggest using [total uninstaller](https://totaluninstaller.codeplex.com) or similar programs.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the Azure SDK to the latest version (showed as an update under tools --> extensions and updates on the updates tab) solved this for me.